# Testing one asset pricing model against another a la Cochrane: a counterexample

Tags: asset-pricing, factor-models

I am reading section section 14.6 of John Cochrane's [lectures notes](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e6033a4ea02d801f37e15bb/t/5f5bfc30caafb27f44aeebd2/1599863856646/week_5_notes.pdf) for the course *Business 35150 Advanced Investments*. On p. 239-240, he discusses testing one asset pricing model against another. I have quite some trouble following his arguments. Here is the essence:

> 1. Example. FF3F.
>    $$
>    E(R^{ei}) = \alpha_i + b_i\lambda_{rmrf} + h_i\lambda_{hml} + s_i\lambda_{smb} \tag{i}
>    $$
>    Do we really need the size factor? Or can we write
>    $$
>    E(R^{ei}) = \alpha_i + b_i\lambda_{rmrf} + h_i\lambda_{hml} \tag{ii}
>    $$
>    and do as well? ($\alpha$ will rise, but will they rise “much”?)

> 2. A common misconception: Measure $\lambda_{smb} = E(smb)$. If $\lambda_{smb} = 0$ (and “small”) we can drop it. Why is this wrong? Because if you drop $smb$ from the regression, $b_i$ and $h_i$ also change!

> <...>

> 4. Solution:
>    (a) “ First run a regression of $smb_t$ on $rmrf_t$ and $hml_t$ and take the residual,
>    $$
>    smb_t = \alpha_{smb} + b_s rmrf_t + h_s hml_t + \varepsilon_t \tag{iii}
>    $$
>    Now, we can drop $smb$ from the three factor model if and only $\alpha_{smb}$ is zero. Intuitively, if the other assets are enough to price $smb$, then they are enough to price anything that $smb$ prices.

---

Below I present a **counterexample** showing that the proposed approach fails. **Where is my mistake?**

Suppose the following 2-factor asset pricing model actually holds:
$$
E(R^{ei}) = \beta_{1,i}E(X_1) + \beta_{2,i}E(X_2). \tag{iv}
$$
Construct a variable $X_3$ such that it is independent of the triplet $(R^{ei},X_1,X_2)$ and let $E(X_3)=\mu_3\neq 0$. Suppose we do not know what the true model is and instead of $(\text{iv})$ we (mistakenly) use
$$
E(R^{ei}) = \tilde\beta_{1,i}E(X_1) + \tilde\beta_{2,i}E(X_2) + \tilde\beta_{3,i}E(X_3). \tag{v}
$$
Let us apply Cochrane's method to assess whether we could do without $X_3$. That is, regress $X_3$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$
$$
X_{3,t} = \delta_0 + \delta_1 X_{1,t} + \delta_2 X_{2,t} + v_t \tag{vi}
$$
and test $H_0\colon \delta_0=0$. By construction of $X_3$, we know that
$$
X_{3,t} = \mu_3 + 0\times X_{1,t} + 0\times X_{2,t} + v_t, \tag{vi'}
$$
and thus $\delta_0=\mu_3\neq 0$. If our test has enough power, $H_0$ will be rejected. By Cochrane's argument, $X_3$ belongs in the model. But we know that this is incorrect.

#### References

- Cochrane, J. H. (2014). [Week 5 Empirical methods notes](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e6033a4ea02d801f37e15bb/t/5f5bfc30caafb27f44aeebd2/1599863856646/week_5_notes.pdf). *Business 35150 Advanced Investments*, 225-247.

Comment: Related questions: [1](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77313), [2](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77531), [3](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77539), [4](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77532), [5](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77541).

Comment: I'm not quite getting your counterexample. You say (iv) holds. That means the expected return of *every* (tradable) asset needs to have this two factor structure. You then suggest to look at another factor, $X_3$ which isn't related to the factors in (iv). But if such a factor exists, then (iv) doesn't hold? Like can you claim to construct $X_3$ if (iv) holds?

Comment: @Kevin, what if $X_3$ has zero betas for $X_1$ and $X_2$? The $(\text{iv})$ model still holds for $X_3$. A question remains whether we can find such an $X_3$ that is also independent of $R^{ei}$. Are you suggesting that is impossible?

Comment: If $X_3$ has zero betas, then $E[X_3]=0$ by (iv) and adding it to a factor model wouldn't really work? If (iv) truly holds, then the return of every tradable asset has to obey that factor structure. So we can't come up with a different portfolio whose return is independent of those factors and has additional pricing power.

Comment: @Kevin, I might be missing something, but on the face of it this looks like a perfect explanation for my puzzle. You have taught me something – that's great! If you write it up and no one points out a mistake in your argument, the bounty is yours. And beyond that also my gratitude and appreciation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on the comments under the question. Suppose the following two-factor model holds
$$
\mathbb E(R^{(i)}) = \beta_1^{(i)}\mathbb E(X_1) + \beta_2^{(i)}\mathbb E(X_2). \tag{iv}
$$
That means the expected return of every tradable asset is fully explained by $X_1$ and $X_2$. These two factors capture *all* variation in expected returns (systematic risk).

Suppose we look at another asset (portfolio) with return $X_3$. By $(\text{iv})$, we know that the expected return needs to have a two factor structure and be fully explained of $X_3$'s betas with respect to $X_1$ and $X_2$. In an equation, we have
$$
\mathbb E(X_3) = \beta_1^{(3)}\mathbb E(X_1) + \beta_2^{(3)}\mathbb E(X_2).
$$
Different to the question, we cannot assume that the expectation of $X_3$ isn't explained by $X_1$ and $X_2$ because that would violate $(\text{iv})$.

If we do not know $(\text{iv})$ is true and use $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ as factors, we get
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(R^{(i)}) &= \beta_1^{(i)}\mathbb E(X_1) + \beta_2^{(i)}\mathbb E(X_2) + \beta_3^{(i)}\mathbb E(X_3) \\
&= (\beta_1^{(i)}+\beta_3^{(i)}\beta_1^{(3)})\mathbb E(X_1) + (\beta_2^{(i)}+\beta_3^{(i)}\beta_2^{(3)})\mathbb E(X_2),
\end{align}
which is again a two-factor model. Essentially, $X_1$ and $X_2$ span the full space already and adding a linear combination of both doesn't help (all with respect to expectations).

Comment: Thank you! On a related note, any thoughts on [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77313) and the answers to it?

Comment: @RichardHardy I actually agree with much that you write in your answer (+1). I'd also add the difference that FM run cross-sectional regressions of returns on characteristics whereas Cochrane's example is about adding tradable factors to a model. It's a slightly different approach.